# Need to combine classes from two python modules into a single class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to combine Classes from two separate Python modules (which are similar in purpose but with different Methods) into a single Class so that the Methods can be accessed from the same object in a natural way both in code and for automatic documentation generation.

I am currently accomplishing the former but not the latter with the following code (this is not verbatim, as I can't share my actual source, but there's nothing different here that would impact the conversation).

Basically, I am creating the new class via a function which combines the `__dict__` attributes of the two child Classes and returns a new Class.

```
def combine(argone, argtwo):
"""
Combine Classes
"""
_combined_arg = "some_string_%s_%s" % argone, argtwo
_temp = type('Temp', (ModuleOne, ModuleTwo), dict())


self = _temp(_combined_arg) # Calling the constructor with our combined arg 
# The two classes have an identical constructor method within their __init__() methods

# Return the object we've instantiated off of the combined class
return self
```

This method works fine for producing an object that lets me call Methods from either of the original Classes, but my IDE can't auto-complete Method names nor can documentation generators (like [pdoc](https://github.com/BurntSushi/pdoc)) produce any documentation beyond our `combine()` function.

This process is necessary because we are generating code off of other code (descriptive, I know, sorry!) and it isn't practical to combine them upstream (ie, by hand).

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!!!

### ADDENDUM:

What I *can* say about what we are doing here is that we're just combining client Methods generated off of REST API endpoints that happen to be split into two, non-overlapping, namespaces for practical reasons that aren't important to this discussion. So that's why simply dropping the methods from ModuleTwo into ModuleOne would be all that needs doing.

If there are suggestions on an automatable and clean way to do this *before* shipping either module, I am definitely open to hearing them. Not having to do this work would be far preferable. Thanks!

Comment: Are `ModuleOne` and `ModuleTwo` (which I assume are classes, not modules) really hard-coded? In that case, why are you defining a new child class everytime you call `combine`? And if you do move the class definition outside of `combine`, then `combine` would appear to simply be a candidate for a class method of the new child. What exactly do you need that is different from a simple child class?

Comment: You're right, they are Classes within Modules that are named identically, sorry for any confusion.

`combine` is only called once, it also does some other work besides just combining them, so it isn't being done _just_ to combine the classes. 

This was done because I could not find a cleaner way to combine the two  Classes before the end user needs to do the "other work" and construct the newly instantiated object. Make any sense? Sorry, not a Python veteran, by any stretch.

Comment: OH, and yes, they are hard-coded. The need is because otherwise, the user would need to instantiate two objects and switch between them for various operations. It also would generate additional network and processing overhead as it would be reproducing work that the two have in common.

Comment: Okay, I also just clarified my example in the original post. my comments in the code were misleading/inaccurate. Hopefully, now, it makes more sense.

Comment: This sounds like a terrible idea. You are going to have all sorts of horrible problems if you try this.

Comment: Thanks for the opinion, I actually have been using the code for a while now and it works great, for the work it's meant to do. I am trying to refine it into something more elegant and able to be maintained more easily via automated documentation processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for `combine` to define a new class every time it is called.

```
class CombinedAPI(APIOne, APITwo):
    @classmethod
    def combine(cls, arg_one, arg_two):
        arg = "some_string_%s_%s" % (argone, argtwo)
        return cls(arg)

obj = CombinedAPI.combine(foo, bar)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I will investigate this suggestion. I want to stress again that the `combine` method does _alot_ more than just combine these classes, including calling some of the methods being combined, but I'm intrigued. I'll report back!

Comment: The point is, you are defining the *same* class every time; the class itself does not depend the arguments to `combine`, only the instance.

Comment: I understand, this only gets called the one time though. Either way, better is better. I'll let you know what I find out. 

Comment: This did exactly what I needed to do. I did have to create the classmethod and use that to construct the instance object, so it's a slight change in usage pattern, but it now functions exactly like I was wanting. Many thanks!